# Where MVC .NET stores profiles data?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api

I have MVC .NET application (client app) and .NET WebAPI (server app). The first one sends to webApi credentials to authenticate profile. If everything is right webApi returns back a token (base64 string) and some custom information (like birthday, posts count etc) in json. In clients app I have singleton named `ProfilesManager` it stores information returned from webApi and check you authorized or not. So, my question: where this information is placed physicly? What happens if one million users authorize and store there information in profile managers? Where all this data placed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Singleton means it is shared across all requests. Since the profile information is going to be specific to to the user, You should be storing this per user session.

Also, Do not store too much information in the per user session data. You should be storing only very minimal information (Ex : Unique token), using which you will be querying other data( ex : Summary of profile etc..) when you load the page. Now the question is whether you want to query the db every time for this or not ? There comes **caching**. Get the data first time and cache it (Check [MemoryCache](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/ff919782(v=vs.100).aspx) class or if you want to go little big, Learn about Redis or similar alternatives).

Comment: Oh, I see. I have a wrong architecture. I need to specify requests between users who do them. Thank you..